# Libcurl SSL certificate verification

Tags: xml, ssl, curl, https, libcurl

I made a simple program to send/receive XML from a server through HTTPS and libcurl. I just disbaled the certificate & server verification by setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST as 0. With this the connection is happening from one machine and able to get XML. But from other machine, I get 77 error from curl always. But when I run curl command with -k option on the error-machine, I get proper XML from server. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html says the above two options are enough, aren't they enough? How can I make the libcurl library to work the same way as curl command in this case?

liburl version, On success machine: curl-7.15.5-9.el5, curl-devel-7.15.5-9.el5.

liburl version, On error-machine :curl-7.19.7-26.el6_1.2.x86_64, curl-7.19.0-8.el6.x86_64, libcurl-7.19.7-26.el6_1.2.i686, libcurl-7.19.7-26.el6_1.2.x86_64

Platfor: Linux, Language: C.

Answer (score 0):

Found :)
the binary was compiled with old lib-curl version 3. but the error-machine has only version 4. Also somebody made a link to version 4 with name of version 3. so after compiling with libcurl4 it worked like charm... :)